# Cannot compare time of cookie created in php

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have two cookies, i have stored cookie data and cookie creation time in it and save it in serialized form.

```
$cookieArray = ['cookiedata' => $this->uri->uri_string(), 'creationTime' => new DateTime()];
$cookie      = [
    'name'   => 'invited',
    'value'  => serialize($cookieArray),
    'expire' => '3600',
];
```

But now i want
to compare both cookie creation time i.e. which one is older for that i am using following code but the result i am getting is wrong.

```
$cookiearray  = $this->input->cookie('invited', true);
$cookieArray1 = unserialize($cookiearray);

if ($cookieArray1['creationTime'] > $cookieArray2['creationTime']) {
    printr('cookie 1 is greater');
} else {
    printr('cookie 2 is greater ');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to store the `timestamp`(known as `epoch`). Use `time()` function to retrieve `epoch` time in PHP and store in your cookie. It will be easy to compare the cookie creation time.

> for more info on unix timestamp headover to official docs on [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php)

You can achieve as given below,

```php
$cookieArray = array(
    'cookiedata' => $this->uri->uri_string(),
    'creationTime'=> time()
);
$cookie = array(
    'name' => 'invited',
    'value' => serialize($cookieArray),
    'expire' => '3600',
);
```

Retrieve the cookie and `deserialize` the value, after that you can compare the time of creation.